# Choosing distinct balls to put into identical urns.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, balls-in-bins

"There are 10 distinct balls that can be put into two identical urns such that no urn is empty. In how many ways can that be done?"

I know how to do this question when the urns are distinct (it's simply 9 choose 1), but when the urns are identical, the first urn containing only 1 ball and the second urn containing 9 balls, is the same thing as the first containing 9 balls and the second containing 1 ball. How do I take account for all the double counting?

Also, is there a more general formula that can account for any number n of identical urns?